# Cannot access mounted drive through samba

Tags: permissions, fedora, samba

So a few drives are mounted to user home via fstab at boot.

```
UUID=XXXX-XXXX  /home/user/10TB exfat   defaults,uid=1000,umask=000 0 0
```

Then I ran this command for samba to access home directory:

```
sudo setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs=on
```

Which now with this smb conf section:

```
[home]
        comment = me-files
        path = /home/user
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        public = yes
        create mask = 0644
        directory mask = 0755
        write list = user
```

I can connect to my PC and access everything except the contents of the drive mounted in ~/10TB.

I have heard of disabling SELINUX, but I don't think that is ideal. I have used samba with arch before and it worked just fine. What am I missing here?

System is Fedora 35 KDE spin.

EDIT: I added `user_allow_other` and `allow_other`in fuse.conf

Comment: Can you add `context=“user_home_t”` to the mountpoint?  The “exfat” filesystem doesn’t support SELinux.

Comment: I did add that value to my fstab, machine will not boot upon start up. Had to go into emergency mode and edit it out in fstab. @jsbillings

Comment: Just so you don’t have to mess with it again in emergency, also add “noauto,x-systemd.automount”. This will prevent it from interfering with boot and make it mount on demand

Comment: But then there is no point to include the parameter if I am just going to bypas it with those options right? By the way it is an exfat fuse drive, I edited to add some options in the fuse conf. Maybe you will know something about that too. @jsbillings

Comment: Adding the systemd option turns it into an automount, which means instead of mounting during boot, it is mounted on first access, so it won’t prevent the OS from booting.

Comment: I see, but then if it fails I will still have to go back and edit the fstab, since systemd will also fail.

Comment: You won’t need to boot into emergency mode. Just edit fstab and the do a `systemctl daemon-reload`. Systemd is quite capable of dealing with a failed automout, it just fails to mount and logs the error to the journal.

Answer (score 1):

So I had to do this:

```
setsebool -P samba_share_fusefs 1
```

https://linux.die.net/man/8/samba_selinux

Then did this just for good measure:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw 1
```

Then you should be good for your fuse mounted drives!

No need to add samba type since that does not work with fuse mounts. Npr is there need to edit the fstab for `context`.

You can check with this:

```
ls -dZ /share
```

Answer (score 0):

Error Message in Windows when I slash-slashed into the samba share:

> Cannot access....

Solution:

Going thru the logs with `less /var/log/messages` or `less journalctl`, the logs will tell you the exact command that you will need to run...that you need to write a rule that will override the current selinux configuration.

I ran `setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro true` and that fixed my issue.  No restart was needed, nor did I have to `systemctl restart smb`.  if you need rw access to the share you simply change out the `ro` for `rw` at the end of the command.